# Loop through rows and input data in their cells

Tags: excel, vb.net

I would like to add a value (from a textbox as number (17) into a cell to the 4-th column (left to right) for every row from 2 to 50,
and another value (textbox as number (57) from 50 to the last row with data in the "A" Column.
So, I have already opened the Excel file, within the code, run the macro in the Excel file and I can save it, but just my first row changes the value to 17 in the 4 column. And I actually don't need to change the first row, I need to input data in a cell from the second row to the last one.

```
Private Sub ReportBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Report_Btn.Click

Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim oBooks As Excel.Workbooks
Dim wsheet As Excel.Worksheet
        
If MORCheckbox.Checked Then
    Dim nowYear As Integer = Date.Now.Year
    Dim MontText As String = MonatTextBox.Text
    Dim path As String = "C:\TEST\" & nowYear & "\" & MontText & ""
    Dim name As String = "\Filename" & MontText & " " & nowYear & ".xlsx"    
    Dim pathandname As String = (path & name)
    If Not Directory.Exists(path) Then
           Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
    End If
      
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oExcel.Visible = False
    oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks
    oBook = oBooks.Open("C:\TEST2\Report - Test.xlsm")
    oExcel.Run("TestMACRO")

    Dim numrows As Integer
    numrows = oBook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    wsheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim range1 As Excel.Range = wsheet.Range("A1")
    For Each cell1 As Excel.Range In range1.Cells
         If numrows >= 2 Or numrows <= 50 Then
             wsheet.Cells(4).value = "17"
          ElseIf numrows >= 51 Then
             wsheet.Cells(4).value = "57"
         End If
         Next

oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
oBook.SaveAs(pathandname, 51) ' 51 == xlsx
oBook.Close()
oBook = Nothing
oExcel.Quit()
oExcel = Nothing

Else
End If
```

The problem is that just the 4-th cell in the first row is changed to 17, and the other row/cells are not changed.

Comment: Your code does exactly what you asked it to do. What exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: Unfortunately it´s not, it´s just changing the 4-th cell in my first row. But I need to run it for all of my rows, actually from the second row untill the last edited row in the excel file.

Comment: the only cell reference you are setting is `wsheet.Cells(4)`.  Instead, uses a row-column notation, i.e. `wsheet.Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex)`.  Also, the `For Each` loop only has one cell to iterate over (`wsheet.Range("A1")`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop should probably look something more like this. You need some way to keep track of your current row and then pass that into the `Cells()` method. I hope this helps and gets you on the right track.

```
Dim currentRow As Long
For currentRow = 2 To numrows Step 1
    If currentRow >= 2 Or currentRow <= 50 Then
        wsheet.Cells(currentRow, 4).value = "17"
    ElseIf currentRow >= 51 Then
        wsheet.Cells(currentRow, 4).value = "57"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: AWESOME. This helped me and I see the problem now. I still had one last correction in the "If" statement I typed "OR" but actually it must be "AND". Now it works perfect. Thank you Michael Z.